# How to to split a list at a certain value

Tags: python, list

given a unique valued list such as `[5,4,9,2,1,7,'dog',9]` is there a way to split it a a certain value? ie

```
[5,4,9,2,7,'dog'].split(4)
= [5,4],[9,2,7,'dog']
[5,4,9,2,7,'dog'].split(2)
= [5,4,9,2], [7,'dog']
```

?

Comment: What's the result supposed to be?  A list of lists or a tuple of lists?

Comment: what if you have more than one 4? Also the answer to your question is no, there is not list method to do what you want

Comment: Should it be an error if the value you are splitting on is not found?

Comment: "given a unique valued list "

Comment: and knowing the element is def present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = [5,4,9,2,7,'dog']
>>> def list_split(l, element):
...     if l[-1] == element:
...         return l, []
...     delimiter = l.index(element)+1
...     return l[:delimiter], l[delimiter:]
...
>>> list_split(mylist, 4)
([5, 4], [9, 2, 7, 'dog'])
>>> list_split(mylist, 2)
([5, 4, 9, 2], [7, 'dog'])
>>> list_split(mylist, 'dog')
([5, 4, 9, 2, 7, 'dog'], [])
```

Comment: what if you have two elements in a list? i.e. `[5, 4, 9, 2, 7, 4, 'dog']`  This doesn't seem to handle those.

Comment: This will also break if the element is at the end due to indexing ;)

Comment: The question specified that all elements are unique. I'll put a (not particularly useful) sanity check for the last element.

Comment: If you want to split by 2 and 2 exist several times, this won't work. example: [5,4,2,9,2,7,'dog',2,5,6].

Comment: That's perfectly fine, because, again, the question clearly stated that each element is unique.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I didn't see the "unique value lists" part.  So you're good there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that will split a list into an arbitrary number of sub-lists and return a list of them, much like a string split.

```
def split_list(input_list,seperator):
    outer = []
    inner = []
    for elem in input_list:
        if elem == separator:
            if inner:
                outer.append(inner)
            inner = []
        else:
            inner.append(elem)
    if inner:
        outer.append(inner)
    return outer

>>> split_list([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,4,3],3)
[[1, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 4], [4]]
```

If the separator element is to be retained on the sub-list to the left, as specifically posed in the question, then this variation will do it:

```
def split_list(input_list,seperator):
    outer = []
    inner = []
    for elem in input_list:
        if elem == separator:
            inner.append(elem)
            outer.append(inner)
            inner = []
        else:
            inner.append(elem)
    if inner:
        outer.append(inner)
    return outer

>>> splitlist.split_list([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,4,3],3)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 3], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: That's a neat function, but it doesn't give the results specified in the question.

Comment: You are right - I didn't see that the separator was to be retained on the left. I think it is a one line fix.

Comment: The `list` elements were guaranteed to be unique, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
def listsplit(l, e):
    try:
        i = l.index(e) + 1
        return l[:i], l[i:]
    except ValueError:
        return l
```

In the case of the element being at the first or last index in the list, one of the returned lists will be empty, but I'm not entirely sure if this is a problem. In the case of `ValueError` from the `list.index` call, you'll have only the list itself returned, but if another behavior is desired, it's pretty simple to change.

Comment: You didn't test it, did you?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I did but not comprehensively. Is there a bug?

Comment: Yeah I think so, too. There's gotta be a shorter solution, though. Btw, since the list is "unique valued", you're doing more than requested, so you might want to advertise that :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ok I have edited the solution so that it works better for unique valued indices. Thanks for the helpful comments >_<

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, but you can pretty easily slice the list you're making using the index method and get the results you show in your example output.

```
>>> l1 = [5, 4, 9, 2, 7, 'dog']
>>> l1[:l1.index(4) + 1], l1[l1.index(4) + 1:]
([5, 4], [9, 2, 7, 'dog'])
```

The '+1' is there because you wanted the needle (4) to appear in the first list.

Note that this splits on the *first* occurrence, which is pretty typical. If you really want a `split` method as in your question, you can subclass list and write your own using something like this.

Comment: This has the same problem that @KronoS pointed out in my answer: breaks when the split element is the last one in the `list`.

Comment: So catch the error? This is representative of an attitude I don't understand at StackOverflow. If you ask a question here, I volunteer to help you get on your way. I'm not going to write code that deals with every corner case you might encounter. That's **your** job.

Comment: I thought the same thing initially, but then I figured that it's pretty reasonable to expect it to work with any element that exists in the `list`. The result isn't very useful, but at least it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

On one line:

```
[x[k+1:x[k+1:len(x)].index(4)+len(x[:k+1])] for k in  [c for c in [-1]+[i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == 4]][:-1] ] + [x[(len(x) - 1) - x[::-1].index(4)+1:len(x)]]
```

The function:

```
def split_list(x, value):
    return [x[k+1:x[k+1:len(x)].index(value)+len(x[:k+1])] for k in  [c for c in [-1]+[i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == value]][:-1] ] + [x[(len(x) - 1) - x[::-1].index(value)+1:len(x)]]
```

It will work in case the separator exists several times, and in cas it exists at thy end or the beginning of the lis.

Details:

- Part 1: `[c for c in [-1]+[i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a == value]][:-1]`
  Get the indexes of occurences of value, append "-1" in the beginning and remove the index of the last occurence.
- `x[k+1:x[k+1:len(x)].index(value)+len(x[:k+1])]`
  Make a slice (let's callet Slice A) of the list starting the first time from 0 (that's why I appended [-1] -1+1=0) and then starting from occurence index +1 (to make the current occurence unreachable) with each occurence index got from Part 1, then I take another slice starting from the curent occurence index +1 ending at thy end of the list, then I look for the first occurence in this slice, I get it; because it was a slice, I add the current offset (the part from beginning + current occurence index +1) to it, at this point I get the position to stop in, this is the end of the slice A. I finally obtain a split section each time.
- I removed the index of the last occurence, coz it is not relevant to calculate anything after that index, so I just apend them at thy end: `+ [x[(len(x) - 1) - x[::-1].index(value)+1:len(x)]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing:

```
def split_list(li, item):
    if item not in li:
        return li
    else:
        return [li[0:li.index(item)+1], li[li.index(item)+1:]]
```

Testing:

```
for item in (5,4,2,'dog'):
    print item, split_list([5,4,9,2,7,'dog'], item)
```

Prints:

```
5 [[5], [4, 9, 2, 7, 'dog']]
4 [[5, 4], [9, 2, 7, 'dog']]
2 [[5, 4, 9, 2], [7, 'dog']]
dog [[5, 4, 9, 2, 7, 'dog'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible but could mess up iterating over all arrays

```
Array.prototype.split = function(e){
   var mark = this.indexOf(e)+1; 
   return [this.slice(0,mark), this.slice(mark)]; 
}
```

So this needs to be included

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, "split", {
    enumerable: false
} );
```

To make sure 'split' doesn't show up in for loops.

and then:

```
[5,4,9,2,7,'dog'].split(7)
//[[5,4,9,2,7], ['dog']]
```